# Can you use a vaadin-button in upload?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin-designer

All the Upload examples show using NativeButton when programmatically creating an Upload. I want to use a Button (vaadin-button) that is part of a Designer layout. When I try this I see the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to detach an element from parent that does not have it.
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.removeChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:123)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.removeChild(Node.java:376)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element.removeFromParent(Element.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:293)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:141)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.GeneratedVaadinUpload.addToAddButton(GeneratedVaadinUpload.java:1344)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload.setUploadButton(Upload.java:276)
```

We are using Vaadin 14 in CDI mode.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more context (code)? As a sanity-check, I tried the [Custom components upload](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/java-examples) example with 14.6.1, and just swapping `NativeButton` to `Button` works fine in that limited example. I probably did not quite understand your situation.

Comment: It works if I create the vaadin Button programmatically, but not if the button is created by designer in the .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the upload button with Designer, you need to drag the button into the upload in the hierarchy, then add slot="add-button" attribute.

Your templates should end up looking like this:

```
<vaadin-upload>
 <vaadin-button slot="add-button">
   Button 
 </vaadin-button>
</vaadin-upload>
```

Note that you must do this in the hierarchy panel.
[image]

If this does not help (maybe you did this already), could you perhaps include some code that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: Works thanks. Be good if this was documented and didnt have to waste hours trying to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created an issue for this improvement in our Designer repository https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2399.

Feel free to comment.